# import file content as string using blender and python

Tags: python, file, blender

Using `file = open( "filename", "r" )` will open a file named `filename` from same directory as the executed script file and works fine. How can I realize this using a python script and a second textfile, both created within of blender file list. Python 3.3 used in Blender always says file not found. Why?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path, or are you trying to stay away from that? (os.path.abspath(path) - same as os.path.join(os.getcwd(),path)

Comment: @sihrc Thanks for this approach. But this way only showed me, that Blender is currently in directory `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\filename` and gives me a hint that the file is not in this directory. I also tried to import a File from any folder via Alt+O into Blender File list, and register-checkbox, but nothing worked. Using a Static path works well, but I need any relative solution. Eather for placing file in same dir as the .blend-file or directly in Blender.